# How to use generics with the current type

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have this base class:

```
public abstract class Parent {
    public void DoSomething() {
        var c=new GenericClass<**ThisInstanceType**>();
        c.DoYourThing();
    }
}
```

What should I put instead **ThisInstanceType** in order to use generics with the type of "this" (the current child instance)?

I cannot change the declaration of `Parent.DoSomething()`. It cannot be `void DoSomething<T>()`.

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoter will explain what she didn't understand.

Comment: You're doing it wrong. If `DoSomething` depends on the type of the child class, it should be generic or virtual and reimplemented in the subclass. (Or the Parent class itself can be generic, as noted.)

Comment: @Dark Falcon: Usually you are right. I should make DoSomething virtual and implement it in the child. But what if I have many childs and the difference is ONLY and will only be the T in GenericClass<T>?

Comment: @Joel, FYI: I was not the downvoter...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do:

```
public abstract class Parent<T> : IParent
{
    public void DoSomething() {
        var c=new GenericClass<T>();
        c.DoYourThing();
    }
}

public sealed class Child : Parent<Child>
{
}
```

and if necessary you could add:

public interface IParent
{
    void DoSomething();
}

BTW: If you include the full complete real life example, I might be able to give you a better solution

The other solution would be to use reflection to get the proper type and call the method at runtime...

Answer (score 1):

If you make your abstract class generic, you can implement it like this:

```
public abstract class Parent<T> where T : Parent<T> {
    public void DoSomething() {
        var c = new GenericClass<T>();
        c.DoYourThing();
    }
 }

public class Child : Parent<Child> {}
```

Comment: The 'where T : Parent' part is not compiled.

Comment: You are right, of course.  It should be `where T : Parent<T>`.  My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

If you really cannot design it properly, you could do it via reflection. I hesitate to suggest that, as you really should be redesigning your interface, but:

```
Type t = typeof(GenericClass<>).MakeGenericType(this.GetType());
object c = Activator.CreateInstance(t);
c.InvokeMember("DoYourThing", BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, c, new object[] {});
```